# C#: generic function that return element from collection based on condition without using delegate

Tags: c#

So i have this function that return element from collection based on condition:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter)
{
    return source.Where(filter);
}
```

Is it possible to implement it without using `delegate\func` ?

Supposed i have `Person` class with several properties:

```
string name;
int age;
```

And `List` of `Person`  objects.

And i want to create function that get condition for example all the `Person` object that there age is bigger then some number.

Comment: Why do not you want to use Func?

Comment: How exactly would you want it to work instead? What do you want to pass other than a delegate?

Comment: This is a question I was asked in a job interview and I did not know the answer

Comment: The guy who ask me the question told me that i need to create kind of interface in my class (for example Person class)

Comment: Without the use of the generic function you can do it by writing the same thing but typed and with the parameters as the filter but that is stupid to do when this generic cover all possible future change.

Comment: Please see my update for more details

Comment: There's another way: using LINQ Expressions. Not easy and definitively not pretty

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto You can't use an expression without a delegate.

Comment: @Servy You can build it without asking for it as a parameter, that's what I meant

Comment: @dannykob Next time, ask the interviewer for the answer. That's the only way to know what they were looking for and actually learn from the interview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess interviewer wants something (useless) like

```
public interface IFilterable
{
     bool Match(string match);
}
public static IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string match) where T: IFilterable
{
    return source.Where(x=>x.Match(match));
}
```

or without any linq-ness

```
public interface IFilterable
{
     bool Match(string match);
}
public static IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string match) where T: IFilterable
{
    foreach(var e in source)
    {
        if(e.Match(match)) yield return e;
    }

}
```

Comment: Any way using this without this x=>x.Match(match) ?

Comment: @dannykob You can't use LINQ without `Func<>`s

Comment: is it possible to implement it without LINQ?

Comment: @dannykob `source.Where` *is* LINQ, not sure what you are talking about

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If they didn't know that Where is a LINQ method then why do you think they'd ask how to implement it without LINQ?

Comment: Well, yeah ("is it possible to implement it without LINQ?"), in a specific case, just write a loop and incorporate the test that's specific to your situation in the loop.  In a general case, you could pass the name of the property, the value to match and play some Reflection games.  Neither measures up to LINQ at all

Answer (score 0):

Your example without the filter can be done in many many ways but here another with the `yeild`

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> GetPersonByMinimumAge(IEnumerable<Person> persons, int age) 
{ 
    foreach(var person in persons)
    {
        if(person.age >= age)
        {
            yield return person;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes a new method for every possible filter, not even close to the original generic code

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes that is exactly it. He asked for a specific filter but getting rid of the func he will have to create many method for each filter anyway.